# Filter git log to show only my changes

Tags: git, version-control

How can I filter the `git log` to show only my changes (excluding the changes committed by other developers)?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You can filter the log by the author for example, so you can filter by your name :

```
git log --author="YourName"
```

or by committer :

```
 git log --committer="YourName"
```

Comment: Also, the results can be made to look more pretty with any number of combinations

    git log --author='Your Name' --oneline --pretty=format:'%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s' --date=short

or

    git log   --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s" --author="Your Name"

Comment: also `-i` enables case-insensitive-regex for the value of `--author`

Answer (score 48):

You should use the [`--author` flag to the `git-log` command](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html#_commit_limiting).

Like so:

```
git log --author="You Name"
```

Part of name is also working:

```
git log --author=Name
```

However if you want to use in a generic script like in [this tip](https://coderwall.com/p/7jbwww), you could do it like this:

```
git log --author="$(git config user.name)"
```

You could then make an alias:

```
git config --global alias.mylog '!git log --author="$(git config user.name)"'
```

You could then just type: `git mylog` and see your commits only.

Comment: git log --author="$(git config user.name)" does not seem to work on Windows. Any suggestions?

Comment: @AndreasPresthammer I'm not sure if you are still wondering about the issue, but if your issue is with setting up an alias, but if you are setting up this alias in a text editor rather than through git bash, you may be having an issue with unescaped double-quotes (at least, I was having such an issue).

In my .gitconfig on Windows, I have these aliases set up, and they are working for me.

`my-history = !git log --author=\"$(git config user.name)\"`

Comment: @AndreasPresthammer If you are running it in `cmd`, it won't work because the command substitution `$()` is a Bash syntax. Thus, no substitution happens and you end up asking Git for an author literally named `$(git config user.name)` who obviously doesn't exist.